# Find all integers $(x,y)$ satisfying $(x+y+11)^2 = x^2 + y^2 + 11^2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Find all integers $(x,y)$ satisfying $(x+y+11)^2 = x^2 + y^2 + 11^2$.

So far,
\begin{align*}
x^2 + y^2 + 121 + 2xy + 22x + 22y &= x^2 + y^2 + 121\\
2xy + 22x + 22y &= 0\\
(2x+22)y &= -22x\\
(x+11)y &= -11x
\end{align*}
At least 1 of $x,y$ must be a multiple of 11?

Dont know where to progress after this. All help appreciated.

Comment: You can write your final equation as $(x + 11)(y + 11) = 121$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** First, dividing your second line by $2$ gives

$$xy + 11x + 11y = 0 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Next, using [Simon's favorite factoring trick](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Simon%27s_Favorite_Factoring_Trick) gives

$$(x + 11)(y + 11) = xy + 11x + 11y + 121 \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Comment: Note that, as this [search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=Simon%27s+favorite+factoring) shows, there are other posts here which explicitly use this factoring "trick", e.g., [How many pairs of (not necessarily positive) integers satisfy the equation $2xy = 6x + 7y$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4082272/602049) and [Find integer solution in equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3458600/602049).

Answer (score 0):

Since $y$ is an integer,$\frac{-11x}{x+11}$ will be an integer. When $\frac{x}{x+11}$ is an integer, it refers that $\frac{11}{x+11}$ is an interger, or $x=0$. Then you can find all such $x$ in this situation. Otherwise $\frac{x}{x+11}$ is not an integer but $\frac{-11x}{x+11}$ is. Thus $x$ is a multiple of $11$, write $x=11k$ where $k$ is an integer and solve $k$ in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=a-11,y=b-11$ in $xy+11x+11y=0$ to get
$$ab=121$$
Since the change of variables is completely reversible in the integers, every divisor of $121$ corresponds one-to-one to a solution: $a=\pm1,\pm11,\pm121$, correspinding to
$$(x,y)=(0,0),(-22,-22),(-10,110),(110,-10),(-12,-132),(-132,-12)$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint for another way**:Very useful the "Simon's trick" cited above by @John Omielan to solve this kind of diophantine equations.We want to give another kind of solution.

From $11=\dfrac{-xy}{x+y}$ we have $-xy=11K$ and $x+y=K$ so we can put $y=11M$ from which $$-xM=K\text { and }x+11M=K\Rightarrow \begin{cases}x=\dfrac{-11M}{M+1}\\y=11M\end{cases}$$  a parametrization of the variables from which immediately the solutions corresponding to $M=0$ and $M=10$ the other being less immediate but not hard to find.